# How does the "more S cells" explanation for becoming a super saiyan makes sense?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

So Akira Toriyama said recently in an interview that Goten and Trunks transforms so easily in super saiyan, because saiyans have some "S cells" for becoming a super saiyan, those who has more transform more easily, and Goten and Trunks inherited them from Goku and Vegeta so that's why they transform more easily than Goku and Vegeta. But Goten and Trunks are half saiyans meaning they should have less "S cells" than Goku and Vegeta, no more. Then how does the "more S cells" explanation for becoming a super saiyan makes sense?

Comment: It's anime. The story is only as consistent as the demands of the current arc.

Comment: How do you know that Goten & Trunks would have half as many S-cells as Goku & Vegeta respectively? If the process of reproduction is same for humans & saiyans (and it should be as Goku, a saiyan, & Chi Chi, a human, were able to produce an offspring) then scientifically, either all the cells of the saiyan will be S-cells or none of them would be S-cells, regardless of whether it's a complete or partial saiyan. But if all the cells of every saiyan are S-cells, then the above argument holds good for partial saiyans only. Not talking scientifically, user37439's must be right about the care given.